# How to resolve Missing closing quote character ' on string, error message

Tags: apex, rest-api, post, cloudingo

I got the code below working: Corrected the (curved) brackets, 'quote signs'. Now at least anonymous execution window is executing without interruption. Even the 400 message, has gone away. Only need to combine the JSON code into a JSON object to execute.

Which means: In the case of a REST API with a JSON payload, 400's are used to indicate that the JSON is invalid in some way according to the API specification for the Cloudingo service. I used the same JSON Body as I used in Postman ; in postman i returned a correct result, in Apex i also receive the correct (concatenated) result. 
I added the login/password (compare code below) and now receive the correct results.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://api.cloudingo.com/rest/CheckRecordForDuplicates');                    
request.setMethod('POST');
//Set the header with the key and password to get access to cloudingo
request.setHeader('CloudingoIntegrationKey','xxxxxxxxx');
request.setHeader('CloudingoIntegrationPassword','yyyyyyyyy');
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
//Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody('{ \n' +  
'    "Fields" : [{  \n'+
'            "Field" : "Name",\n' +
'            "Data" : "Palo Alto Networks"\n'+             
'        }\n'+ 
'    ]  \n'+
'                }   \n'
);
//Parse the entire JSON response
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
if(response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    System.debug('Response ' + response.getBody());
} else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}
```

Comment: is the `);'` at the end of your multi-line `request.setBody()` a typo, or is that actually in your code?

Comment: Looks like every edit you're making is undoing the code formatting. In a nutshell, to make code look nice on stackexchange sites you need to add 4 blank spaces to the start of every line. When you're writing or editing a post, there's a button, `{}`, that does that for you. Highlight the code to format, push that button, and presto! You can also press `ctrl` + `k` (`cmd` + `k` on mac) to do the same thing (after highlighting the text to format, that is).

Comment: Also, there is going to be a point where it makes more sense to make a new question than continue editing this one. I like to think that questions asked here are as much for the person asking the question as it is for everyone else coming from [search engine of choice here]. If the topic of the question changes too much, it makes existing answers less relevant and it's harder for others to follow the progression from problem -> explanation -> solution

Comment: thanks, will follow the advice

Comment: Please don't edit your post to remove all its content.

Answer (score 1):

Apex doesn't allow multiline string literals. You'll need to quote that JSON line by line, and add newlines via `'\n'`.

```
request.setBody('{ \n' +  
'    "Fields" : [{  \n'+
'            "Field" : "Name",\n' +  
'            "Data" : "Palo Alto Networks"\n'+  
'        }\n'+
'    ]  \n'+
'                }   \n'
);
```

Comment: I changed the code ; now i am getting a Line: 7, Column: 16
Unexpected token '('. error:     Its the line with request.setBody('{

Comment: @BartSporken I accidentally quoted the close parenthesis.

Comment: i changed the close parenthesis. Now again i have the missing quote ' error?

Comment: @BartSporken I'm sorry, it's too early in the morning for me! THere was a spurious + sign. The key here is that you quote each line, and use `+` after each line that continues to the next.

Comment: Yes, it's 5:30am for me too. I added + after each line that continues to the next; still the missing quote ' character on string